# Checkbox group inside Formik component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm having trouble keeping track of checkboxes in [`<Formik>`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/). When you select a schema it renders the appropriate X amount of checkboxes. When one is selected it should update in the props values. The initial checkbox state lives inside `TableRowWithCheckbox`

```
 export default class TableRowWithCheckbox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { initialState } = this.props;
    this.state = {
      fieldCheckbox: initialState
    };
  }

  checkbox = () => {
    this.setState({ fieldCheckbox: !this.state.fieldCheckbox }, () => {
      console.log("checkbox --> ", this.state.fieldCheckbox);
      const { name, dataType, position, box } = this.props;
      box({
        name,
        dataType,
        position,
        isChecked: this.state.fieldCheckbox
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      name,
      dataType,
      position,
      handleChange
    } = this.props;
    const { fieldCheckbox } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Table.Row>
          <Checkbox
            style={{ marginTop: "20px", marginLeft: "10px" }}
            name="selectedFields"
            checkbox
            onChange={this.checkbox}
          />
          <Table.Cell>{name}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{dataType}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>{position}</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>
            <Input
              onChange={e => handleChange(e, name)}
              value={this.state.size}
              type="number"
              name="size"
              min="1"
              placeholder="1"
              disabled={!this.state.fieldCheckbox}
              required
            />
          </Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>
            <Input
              onChange={e => handleChange(e, name)}
              value={this.state.maxArrayElements}
              type="number"
              name="maxArrayElements"
              placeholder="1"
              min="1"
              max="100"
              disabled={!this.state.fieldCheckbox}
              required
            />
          </Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Then inside the main component the `TableRowWithCheckbox` component is rendered inside the `<Formik>` component with the appropriate `props`. I'm not sure how to hook this custom component to Formik.

```
    <TableRowWithCheckbox
      id={name}
      name={name}
      dataType={dataType}
      value={values.selectedFields}
      position={position}
      initialState={Object.keys(
        selectedFields
      ).includes(name)}
      box={this.checkbox.bind(this)}
      handleChange={this.onChange}
    />
  </React.Fragment>
```

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-create-query-schema-uomqg) with the code

Comment: Just to confirm you don't actually want to save the checkbox value to Formik's state? Looking at your codesandbox I'm assuming you want to save the value in the `input`s that the checkbox enables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

`handleChange={this.onChange}`

to

`handleChange={handleChange}`

this will ensure that `Formik`'s `handleChange` function is used.